# Create websql for the browser not just for one page

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I create a DB and their tables in safari with javascript and insert/delete/edit records very easy and nice. the matter is this DB is in one page. I can not see it when I navigate to other pages. It is not like local storage that is global for all browser. It works just for one page! It keeps data from previous sessions that means every thing is ok. But why I can not see the DB from anther pages of the browser?

```
var db;

function created(){
   var shortName = 'tata'; 
   var version = '1.0'; 
   var displayName = 'tata'; 
   var maxSize = 65536; 
   db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
.........
```

this code is inside a separate file.js that I included in the first page of app. It checks for database and tables and create them if they are not exists.

Answer (score 0):

OK
I found it.
We need to put this part out of any functions to be global. The database is there but we can not see it in browser.resources until we open the connection to DB, So here is the code:

```
var db;
var shortName = 'tata'; 
var version = '1.0'; 
var displayName = 'tata'; 
var maxSize = 65536; 
db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

function created(){ 
.........
```

Do not forget to include this file in all html header files.